# Blazor render specific content based on roles

Tags: authorization, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a table where I am looping through my model of row items. I want to show a delete button to users who are in the Role: `Admin`. How do I do this in Blazor?

I have tried

```
 <AuthorizeView Roles="Admin">
              <MudButton> ADMIN ONLY BUTTON</MudButton>
 </AuthorizeView>
```

Now, this all seems to work fine, except for the fact that the `AuthorizeView` changes my context. So I now lose reference to the Model which I am working on, so Now I want to add an `OnClick` Listener to redirect to `device/delete/{@contenxt.DeviceId}`  and VS now moans to say the context does not have a reference to `DeviceId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename one of the contexts to avoid the conflict:

```
<AuthorizedView Roles="Admin" Context="SomeOtherName" >
              <MudButton> ADMIN ONLY BUTTON</MudButton>
</AuthorizedView>
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is making an assumption - `AuthorizedView` is a type and you mean `AuthorizeView` and not some custom `AuthorizedView` component.

`AuthorizeView` sets the context for it's content to the current `AuthenticationState`.  Hence `{@contenxt.DeviceId}` doesn't work - there's no `DeviceId` on `AuthenticationState`.

As you haven't show much "context" for your question - apologies for the pun! - I'm assuming you're iterating through a list and showing an edit button for each record.  If so, you can set a local loop variable to your context outside `AuthorizeView` and then refer to that in your button call.

Something like:

```
@{
    var device = context;
}
 <AuthorizedView Roles="Admin">
              <MudButton @onclick="() => GotToEdit(device.DeviceId)"> ADMIN ONLY BUTTON</MudButton>
 </AuthorizedView>
```